# How can I get access to related entities with Symfony doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I try to find all documents that are related to my product:

```
public function findDocumentsRelatedToProduct($id) {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('products')
                        ->leftJoin('products.documents', 'pd')
                        ->where("products.id = :id")
                        ->setParameter(':id', $id)
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->execute();

}

$products = $this->em->getRepository('App\\Entity\\Products')->findDocumentsRelatedToProduct($id);

foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
    dump($value->getDocuments()->getId());
}
```

But I get the error message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getId" of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$value->getDocuments()` return an array of Doctrine objects, or a `PersistentCollection`.

Your object may have a `getId()` function, but the `PersistentCollection` doesn't.

You can loop over the Collection :

```
foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value->getDocuments() as $document) {
        dump($document->getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getDocuments()` returns a collection of multiple `product.documents`. So you need to iterate over those documents aswell, and then use `->getId()` on the single items.